# Javascript filtering algorithm return values don't match with Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

I'm making a modeling tool in Google Sheets and part of it needs to count how many rows match all of the conditions given. When I check what it returns with the Sheets FILTER formula the number don't match (less values in script). Here's the code:

```
function logisticFilterBelow (filterSet,parameters,upBound,lowBound,start=2,yIndex=0){
  //returns the number of values and y value of the data set that are below calculated value (parameters) and in bounds
  //In default configuration, the first two columns will be the y value and b0 (constant value in equation 
  
  var data = []
  var count = 0
  var success = 0

  for (a=0;a<filterSet.length;++a){
    var bool = true
    for (s=start;s<parameters.length+1;++s){ //checks if all conditions are met for each value in row
       bool = bool && filterSet[a][s]<=parameters[s-1]
       bool = bool && filterSet[a][s]<=upBound[s-1]
       bool = bool && filterSet[a][s]>=lowBound[s-1]
       }
      //updates the return stats
      count += bool ? 1: 0
      success += bool ? filterSet[a][yIndex]:0

    }
  success = count >0 ? success/count : "NA" //brings the average value of y or NA when there were no values

  data.push(count,success) //simple array to bring both values

  return data
}
```

The function argument filterSet is the 2D array of the google sheet data and optimization suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you post a sample spreadsheet with the formula, script and data to demonstrate the result? Or at least some data and the formula to test it with.

Comment: I found out that the formula was ok, the problem was on how I set my FILTER function check. Anyway, feedback regarding the code is always welcome and this is an open project I'm making, so here's the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12HaukahFWy0aqA3HnhiwfeCcAHFHWu6Q0ylW7QCRIbY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I will take a look! Though I would encourage you to post the answer to your question below as an answer for reference for future viewers, in case they run into a similar issue.